# Projecting polygon using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, coordinate-system, geometry-service

I have polygon data as:

> POLYGON ((1645481.0939999996 6124506.9885, 1645470.0473999996
>   6124473.5406, 1645475.7094 6124440.1391,1645481.0939999996 6124506.9885))
>
> in wkid=2193

I want to project this polygon using geometry service with new spatial reference wkid= 3857.

I was able to project point using similar data on new spatial reference wkid=3857, but that is not happening with polygon.

Which method should I use to project polygon using geometry service?

```
 function addGraphic() {

   var wkt = new Wkt.Wkt(); 
   wkt.read("POLYGON ((1645481.0939999996 6124506.9885, 1645470.0473999996   6124473.5406, 1645475.7094 6124440.1391,1645481.0939999996 6124506.9885))");
  var polygon = wkt.toObject();

  //set the spatialreference
  polygon.SpatialReference = new esri.SpatialReference({wkid: 2193});
  var outSR = new esri.SpatialReference({ wkid: 3857 });
  var gsvc = new esri.tasks.GeometryService("http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");

   var projPoly;
   gsvc.project([polygon], outSR, function (outGeom) {

   projPoly = outGeom[0];

   var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol().setStyle(esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID);
   var polygonGraphic = new esri.Graphic(projPoly, symbol);
   map.graphics.add(polygonGraphic);

  });
 }
```

Comment: user esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_NULL

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues that you need to solve.

- Firstly, the polygon that you have, is in a format that is called the [WKT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text#Geometric_objects). You will have to convert it to a geometry in the ESRI's JavaScript format. I have used [Wicket](https://github.com/arthur-e/Wicket) in the past to do this conversation for me.
- Once you have an ESRI Polygon, you can use the [project operator](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/geometryservice-amd.html#project) on the GeometryService. You should make sure that you set the spatialreference on the polygon, before you send it to the service.

You can use code similar to this:

```
    function projectToWebMercator() {

        var wkt = new Wkt.Wkt();
        wkt.read("POLYGON ((1645481.0939999996 6124506.9885, 1645470.0473999996 6124473.5406, 1645475.7094 6124440.1391,1645481.0939999996 6124506.9885))");
        var polygon = wkt.toObject();
        //set the spatialreference
        polygon.setSpatialReference(new SpatialReference({
                wkid : 2193
            }));

        var outSR = new SpatialReference({
                wkid : 102100
            });
        var gsvc = new GeometryService("http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");
        gsvc.project([polygon], outSR, function (outGeom) {
            console.dir(outGeom); //<-- Do whatever you want with the projected Polygon here
        });
    }
```

Comment: I've tried to convert WKT to a geometry using http://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/sandbox-arcgis.html, but its not showing up anything. Can you please send me some sampple code? I had similar coordinates for point, but when I project them using new spatial reference and geometry service, it worked. Please guide me.

Comment: @Dips: I've added the code. Don't forget to add the two scripts from Wicket in you HTML file.

Comment: hey..Thanks for the code, but still not getting those two scripts to add from Wicket, please guide me.

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'not getting those scripts' did you download those scripts from github?

Comment: I've added scripts and modified code as per your directions, but still its not showing up polygon on the map. Please check my above edited code. If I modify polygon data i.e. add more coordinates to it around 40 coordinates, it  doesn't call gsvc.project method.

Comment: You need to debug line by line with something like Firebug, or Chrome's developer tools, and see which line gives you the error.

Comment: I've debugged using Chrome's developer tools and it gives following error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/info?f=json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'myserver' is therefore not allowed access.`  I've tried out few solutions, but still same problem.